# How can we remove caret sign from drop down in ion-select.I don't want to show any icon.Only text should be shown

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ion-select

I want to remove that default caret sign.I don't want to show any `icon`.I have **html and .ts** 
   files.I am using `ionic 4 and angular 7`.I only want to display "`select`" label with no caret 
    button along with it.

**Here is my code:-**

**Home.html :**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

    <ion-item>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <h4 style="opacity: 0.5">Description</h4>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Select</ion-label>
        <ion-select interface="popover">
            <ion-option *ngFor="let option of options">
                <h2>{{ option.title }}</h2>
                <h4>{{ option.description }}</h4>
            </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

I want to remove that default caret sign.I don't want to show any icon.I have html and .ts 
    files.I am using ionic 4 and angular 7.I only want to display "select" label with no caret 
    button along with it.
Here is my .ts file below:

**home.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

 @Component({
 selector: 'page-home',
 templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
 export class HomePage {

       options = [
       {
          title: 'Banana',
          description: 'Long curved yellow fruit.'
       },
       {
            title: 'Dog',
            description: 'Man\'s best friend.'
      },
      {
           title: 'Ionic',
           description: 'Modificates the options text.'
      }
   ];
          constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

  }
```

Comment: for that case can’t you use ion-button and alert-controller if you require such customization?

Comment: Please elaborate or share the link for understanding.